# Alternative to iFrames with AJAX

Tags: ajax, iframe

What are the best alternatives to iFrames with AJAX?

iFrames are not the best way to inject HTML into a website page that is on another site, I would love to know of a technology that does this, I prefer AJAX.

This iFrame will be on other peoples sites, so we don't have access to other users site, just the internal iFrame.

Comment: i believe u need to add more clarification

Comment: While that clarification helped a bit, you still aren't really spelling out your requirements. Why don't iframes work for you? What, specifically, are you trying to do; simply load a fragment of a page and put it somewhere in your current page? Do you need to be able to update it later? Your question is still not really specific enough to be answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're looking to do is load some content from another page and insert it into your current page, I'd recommend using [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) from [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

Assuming you want to load the content in an element with ID `fragment`, it would work something like this:

```
$('#fragment').load('some/page.html')
```

Note that this can only be used for pages from the same origin as your script. If you need to load pages across origins, `iframe` is the easiest way (though you don't get access to the inner page from the outer page).

In order for the AJAX example to work across domains, you could use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) to allow requests between domains, but the page which is being included must explicitly allow itself to be included; you can't get arbitrary content from another domain.